# GradleException error when trying to commit code to local Git

Tags: git, android-studio, flutter

Started new Flutter project in Android Studio and did not change boiler plate code.
Project runs fine in emulator.
Created local GIT depository, selected all files and committed project.
I can explain/solve all errors in Code analysis EXCEPT for this one:

Error:(11, 15) Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException' (See image below)

[image]

Local.properties file (See image below)

[image]

Flutter Doctor output (See Image below)

[image]

The same problem occurs in my customer project as well (same project settings).
I have been breaking my head for some time now but can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Pierre.

Comment: That's normal. You should be able to just commit anyway.

Comment: That is correct Richard but still I was wondering why the error is generated. I have now found a solution/work around.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/workaround to my question on Github. Vladyslav Bondarenko kindly pointed me in the right direction.
For those of you who are interested:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29608

I followed the procedure from Jasondphan to the letter and it worked.
You have to add it to each project though.

Pierre.